# Python: comparing three lists and not storing the same number twice

Tags: python, for-loop, append, break, enumerate

I have three lists:

```
    list1 = [10, 20, 30]
    list2 = [22, 19, 32]
    list3 = [18, 21, 28]
```

I want to filter each list so that I remove a number that is not within 5 digits to another number in both the other two lists.  However, I don't want any number being used twice.  Here's my code:

```
    output1 = []
    output2 = []
    output3 = []

    for i, valuei in enumerate(list1):
        for j, valuej in enumerate(list2):
            for k, valuek in enumerate(list3):
                delta1_2 = list1[i] - list2[j]
                delta2_3 = list2[j] - list3[k]
                if abs(delta1_2) < 5 and abs(delta2_3) < 5:
                    output1.append(valuei)
                    output2.append(valuej)
                    output3.append(valuek)
                    k=k+1
                    break
                else:
                    continue
    print(output1, output2, output3)
```

However, my output looks like this:

> [20, 20, 30]  [22, 19, 32]  [18, 18, 28]

I want it to come out like this (I want "20" to be used only once and then move on to "30" in list1):

> [20, 30]  [22, 32]  [18, 28]

Comment: I am unclear as to why 19 is removed from the second list and 21 is removed from the third list. 19 is within 5 of 22, 18, and 21; and 21 is within 5 of 20, 22, and 19. Shouldn't that mean the only number removed from your output is 10?

Comment: I am looking for 3 numbers, each in a different list, that are within 5 digits of each other.  I am not comparing values to other values in the same list.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're asking for (not using any number twice) is possible in this situation. If 10 isn't within 5 digits of any number in the other two lists, that doesn't tell anything about whether 20 is within 5 digits of any number in the other two lists. So eventually you have to use some numbers twice unless you know a relationship within each list or between the lists.

Comment: 20 from the first list, 19 from the second list, and 21 from the third list are all within 5 of each other and from different lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'set' funtion for it:

```
    output1 = []
output2 = []
output3 = []

for i, valuei in enumerate(list1):
    for j, valuej in enumerate(list2):
        for k, valuek in enumerate(list3):
            delta1_2 = list1[i] - list2[j]
            delta2_3 = list2[j] - list3[k]
            if abs(delta1_2) < 5 and abs(delta2_3) < 5:
                output1.append(valuei)
                output2.append(valuej)
                output3.append(valuek)
                k=k+1
                break
            else:
                continue
print(set(output1), set(output2), set(output3))
```

Comment: output is now [20,30] [32,19,22] [18,28].  I would like it to be [20,30] [22,32] [18,28].  I would like the outer for-loop to iterate to the next value after "20" in list1 after it has found a number in each of the other two lists within 5 digits. Right now the code is staying on "20" and looping through the inner two for-loops looking for more values within the 5 digit range.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking does not match your examples...

```
def within(x, n, ys):
    return any(abs(x - y) < n for y in ys)

def filter(list_in, list_to_compare):
    return [x for x in list_in if within(x, 5, list_to_compare)]
```

For your inputs:

```
list1 = [10, 20, 30]
list2 = [22, 19, 32]
list3 = [18, 21, 28]

print(filter(list1, list2 + list3))
print(filter(list2, list1 + list3))
print(filter(list3, list1 + list2))
```

prints:

```
[20, 30]
[22, 19, 32]
[18, 21, 28]
```

19 and 21 are within 5 from 20 from list1, so they should not be filtered out.

Comment: I want all lists to contain the same amount of values.  You are correct in that 19 and 21 are within 5 of 20, but 20 should be already matched with 22 and 18.

Comment: This is not what you asked for in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Much credit to my friend for solving this.

```
    list1 = [10, 20, 30]
    list2 = [22, 19, 32]
    list3 = [18, 21, 28]

    output1 = []
    output2 = []
    output3 = []

    keepGoing = True
    matchFound = False
    while(keepGoing):
            matchFound = False
            for i, valuei in enumerate(list1):
                if(matchFound):
                    break
                else:
                    for j, valuej in enumerate(list2):
                            if(matchFound):
                                    break
                            else:
                                    for k, valuek in enumerate(list3):
                                            delta1_2 = list1[i] - list2[j]
                                            delta2_3 = list2[j] - list3[k]
                                            if abs(delta1_2) < 5 and abs(delta2_3) < 5:
                                                    matchFound = True
                                                    output1.append(list1[i])
                                                    output2.append(list2[j])
                                                    output3.append(list3[k])
                                                    list1 = list1[i+1:]
                                                    list2 = list2[j+1:]
                                                    list3 = list3[k+1:]
                                                    if not list1 or not list2 or not list3:
                                                            keepGoing = False
                                                    break

    print((output1), (output2), (output3))
```

Output:

> [20,30] [22,32] [18,28]